# CKEDITOR: Listblock / Richcombo toolbar plugin: onmouseover action ingegration

Tags: plugins, ckeditor, toolbar, onmouseover

I would like to trigger some action on a mouseover event on a listblock toolbar derivate plugin (to be exact: the richcombo plugin).

I played around with some adaptions in listblock plugin itself, and also checked how floatpanel (and panel) is working...
Finaly I've come close (at least I'm thinking I'm getting close) and found

> listItem = CKEDITOR.addTemplate( 'panel-list-item' ...

in listblock Line 12.

There I see the

> onclick="CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction({clickFn}...

integration, that finaly ends up in the HTML List code.

I've also found the target function that is called by clicking a list item, 
the code is in the richcombo plugin (around Line 297):

> list.onClick = function( value, marked ) {

But now I'm somehow stuck. 
How does the CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction({clickFn} in the list item HTML finaly trigger the list.onClick function?

Is there any {mouseoverFn} I could add to an

> onmouseover=CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction({mouseoverFn}...

next to the onclick event in listblock? How could I properly implement the mouseoverFn?
And how it would trigger then a hypothetical

> list.OnMouseover = function (...

function (to be implemented) in the richcombo code ?

Any hints and maybe an example would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance,

Stoney

Comment: I implemented a not so nice but working hack: onmouseover=CKEDITOR.myFunction into the Listblock plugin as mentioned above and adding the myFunction to the CKEDITOR. It is working without the CKEDITOR.tool.callFunction, but at least it is working and doing what I want...

Comment: Finally found proper integration myself... read comment in main thread

Answer (score 1):

Found the proper integration myself:

Add the following like the {onclick} in the listblock plugin just after the {onclick} (line 15):

> ' {onmouseover}="CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction({mouseoverFn},\'{val}\');return false;"' +

Add the following like the getClick: function() in the listblock plugin just after the getclick: function() (around line 83):

> ```
>           getMouseover: function() {
>                 if ( !this._.mouseover ) {
>                     this._.mouseover = CKEDITOR.tools.addFunction( function( value ) {
>                         var marked = this.toggle( value );
>                         if ( this.onMouseover )
>                             this.onMouseover( value, marked );
>                     }, this );
>                 }
>                 return this._.mouseover;
>             }
> ```

Add the following like the "onclick: CKEDITOR.env.ie ?..." entry in the listblock plugin just after the "onclick: CKEDITOR.env.ie ?..." statement (around line 111), (but not sure if it is also correct for IE browsers):

> onmouseover: CKEDITOR.env.ie ? 'onmouseover="return false;" onmouseup' : 'onmouseover',
>   mouseoverFn: this._.getMouseover(),

Now add the following like the "list.onClick = function(..." in the richcombo plugin, just after the "list.onClick = function(...":

> ```
>           list.onMouseover = function( value, marked ) {
>                 if ( me.onMouseover )
>                 {
>                     console.log('me.onMouseover');
>                     me.onMouseover.call( me, value, marked );
>                 }
>                 //panel.hide();
>             };
> ```

Now finaly, in your own plugin, where you build the dropdown combobox, just use your freshly implemented onMouseover function, like you would use the onClick function:

> ```
>       onMouseover: function( value )
>         {
>             // do here whatever is needed for your mouseover action...
>         },
> ```

Cheers and enjoy.